# How to call java function using onclick event in <a> tag from jsp page

Tags: java, jsp

I want to call a java function named setrowNumber(1), that sets the row number to a static int variable.
And I want this function to be called when the link is clicked but that does'nt seem to happen.

The problem is in that part only because when i try to set the value manually it works fine.

```
<a   href="single.jsp" onclick= "<%conc.setrowNumber(1);%>" > <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right icon"  ></i></a>
```

I am making java web application on struts framework, using net beans and wamp server.

If I use javascript function and use it with onclick event then how can I pass value to java function.e.g

```
<a   href="single.jsp" onclick= "myFunc(1)" > <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right icon"  ></i></a>


<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunc (int a) {
<% conc.setrowNumber(a); %> //how to write java function and pass value here because a is not known var here.         
}
</script>
```

Comment: An `onclick` event handler is executed in the browser. Normally this would be JavaScript. JSP scriptlets are executed on the server before the page is sent to the browser. You could have a scriptlet that generates some JavaScript and embeds it in the page as an `onclick` handler, or you could have an `onclick` handler that sends an XmlHttpRequest to a servlet or JSP to execute some function on the server. But your current approach doesn't make sense.

Comment: I edited the question please check again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is normally done with an AJAX call in JavaScript, in asynchrone mode: you send to the server, and possibly register a JavaScript function to call back. A web search will give examples. In your case. a link, you could assign to the href location an url with the parameter.

```
this.href.url = "single.jsp?a=" + a;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. 
`<s:url id="yourId" action="yourActionName"></s:url>
<s:a href="%{#yourId}"><img src="<s:url value="/images/submit.png" /> </s:a>`

Make a link on jsp and through that url you can call the Action.

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
        <a   href="#" onclick= "<% conc.setrowNumber(1); %> return false;" > <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right icon"  ></i></a>
```

Comment: Returning false won't load the page.

Comment: yep if you need to call java function then it should not reload the page till code execute then you can call js method to reload the page

Answer (score -1):

Include the class which has got this function in your jsp like this

```
<%@page import="package.subPackage.TheClassName"%>
```

In the  scriptlet tag you can invke the method.

`<%
   TheClassName theClassInstance = new TheClassName();
   theClassInstance.doSomething();
%>`

If its a static method you don't need to create instance .

Comment: I have done this, but my problem is that I want to call the function on Onclick event and pass parameter but I can't understand how.The function is not being invoked.

Comment: why do people write garbage answers like this?